# c# query rdlc report from listview

Tags: c#, rdlc, reportviewer, dataadapter

I need to generate report with querying where itemcode = foreach listview2.text

```
data1DBDataSetTableAdapters.itmscat1TableAdapter adapter = new data1DBDataSetTableAdapters.itmscat1TableAdapter();
data1DBDataSet.itmscat1DataTable table = new data1DBDataSet.itmscat1DataTable();

foreach (ListViewItem item1 in listView2.Items)
{
    item1int = Convert.ToInt32(item1.Text);
    adapter.FillBy3(table, item1int));
}

ReportDataSource mynewdatasource = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", (DataTable)table);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(mynewdatasource);
this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

The code runs correct but it only get first item and not all items in listview.

How to get all items in listview not only the first one ?

EDIT : FillBy3 method :

```
select * where itmcode = @itmcode
```

Comment: Hi, This code do not seem right, Variable `item1int` is defined in the `foreach` loop and used after the loop...

Comment: First item? Surely you mean the last? In the loop you overwrite the contents of `item1int` each time but you never "use" it. Add it to the table inside the loop.

Comment: I changed it but still gives the same result

Comment: Any suggestion on what should i change in my code ?

Comment: No, because we don't know what `FillBy3` does, or what the methods on `itmscat1TableAdapter` are.

Comment: Select * from itmscat1 where itmcode = @itmcode

Comment: Showing a single line of SQL when asked for the implementation of `FillBy3` is insufficient. The full C# code of that method is needed.